# JS/CSS Loading spinner finishes before JS executes

Tags: javascript, html

Kinda JS/dev newbie here. Having a play around with a loading spinner - [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-show-page-loading-div-until-the-page-has-finished-loading/) is the example I'm working from. I've currently got a bunch of JS calculations that are performed on a Flask/SQLite backend API. I'll ignore the CSS as it's likely irrelevant.

```
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (document.readyState !== "complete") {
        document.querySelector("main").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.querySelector("#loader").style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        document.querySelector("#loader").style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector("main").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
};
```

This in the html:

```
<main role="main" class="container">
    <div id="loader" class="spinner-1"></div>
    ...content here...
</main>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for ('static', filename='scripts/main.js') }}"></script>
```

The issue is that the JS is still running on DOM load. So the spinner disappears and items are still being added to the DOM via JS. They appear after the spinner disappears, which negates the point of having a spinner!

I've tried several of [these](https://codetonics.com/javascript/detect-document-ready/) methods, but they all work the same.

I thought about having the conditional tied to one of the loading items, but that seems a bit clunky and I'd not be able to repeat the code on other pages on the site. Is there a baked in JS method for doing this properly?

EDIT - some of the JS I'm using

```
async function recipeGet () {
    let response = await fetch('/recipeget/' + recipeId)
    let data = await response.json();
    return data
};

recipeGet();

async function efficiency () {
    let mEfficiency = (await recipeGet()).efficiency;
    mEfficiency = mEfficiency / 100
    return mEfficiency
}

async function insertEff () {
    let eff = await efficiency();
    let effElement = document.querySelector('#eff');
    effElement.innerText = (((Math.round(abv * 100) / 100 )) + "%");
};

insertEff();
```

I appreciate this may not be the right way to do things, but I'm still relatively new to developing, and it works currently.

ANSWER:

With the suggestion of the answer below, I managed to implement this:

#### JS

```
async function insertEff () {
    let eff = await efficiency();
    let effElement = document.querySelector('#eff');
    effElement.innerText = (((Math.round(abv * 100) / 100 )) + "%");
    document.querySelector("#loader").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector("#spins").style.visibility = "visible";
};
```

#### HTML

```
        <div id="loader" class="spinner-1"></div>
        <div class="tab-content" id="spins">
```

#### CSS

```
#spins {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Where spins is the ID of the division I want to hide. It is initially hidden, then unhides when the function is executed. I still have to toy around with the HTML as the spinner jigs around a bit on page load, but that's a relatively trivial problem.

Comment: Or have I just got my JS wrong? there's a bunch of API calls and async functions, happy to post some demo code here if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would maybe change how you're receiving the data on your front end.  It seems like you're trying to directly add the data from the back end to the front end using some kind of template.

Instead of doing this, try doing a fetch request from the front end after the page is loaded.  That way you get the page much faster, and your spinner will be coordinated with the data you receive, meaning it will only disappear once you have all the data.

Here's an example of an ajax/fetch request:

```js
const API_URL = 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=3'

const dataWrapper = document.querySelector('.data-wrapper')
const spinner = document.querySelector('.spinner')
const data = document.querySelector('.data')

const fetchData = async (URL) => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(URL)
    const json = await res.json()
    
    // populate data with json
    data.innerText = JSON.stringify(json, undefined, 2)
    
    spinner.remove() // or just make display: none; - whatever you need
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err.message)
  }
}

fetchData(API_URL)
```

```css
.data-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.spinner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: blue;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

@keyframes spin {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.data {
  background: lightgray;
  color: #235789;
  font-family: 'Cascadia Code', monospace;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="data-wrapper">
  <div class="spinner">
    <i class="fas fa-spinner"></i>
  </div>
  
  <pre class="data"></pre>
</div>
```

The point is, by doing an ajax call in this way, the line where the spinner gets removed will only be reached and executed once the data is fully received.

Comment: The existing set up is Flask + Jinja, and I'm using an API to grab some data from the backend and perform calculations on it.

Comment: Some of the data is populating the template on page load, but the JS is performing calculations by grabbing data from the backend, then loading it into the page.

Comment: I see.  It's also good that you updated your question.  In that case, just change the visibility of your loader in the `insertEff` function (or whichever async function you want).  That way the spinner will only leave once the data is all loaded.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense - nice and simple and it ties in with my JS. Running on a timer will work but it'd be nice to have it running as soon as the data is loaded.

Comment: Yeah, just like what's in the fetchData function in the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.querySelector('#loader').style.opacity = '0';
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.querySelector('#loader').style.display = 'none';
            document.querySelector('main').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }, 200);
    }, 1000);
}
```

I use this code to make my preloader smooth and hide after 1 second of window onload. Maybe this code will help you.

Comment: thanks for the answer dude! Gonna accept the other one as the answer as it relies on the functions finishing rather than a timer which I'd have to dial in a bit more.